# Entity reference value from url in node add form block

Tags: forms, entities

I have a content type book and another content type pages.
A page has a entity reference field to book.
Now, I want to allow users to create pages on the same page as book. So, I created a page add form using formblock module.

I would like to have the entity reference field auto generated and pointing to the book.

Is it possible? 
Thanks. :)

Comment: I am using form block and entity reference prepopulate. But , have not been successful so far.

Answer (score 1):

[Node Reference URL Widget](http://drupal.org/project/nodereference_url) can help you :)

Comment: Didn't work with nodeform block. Looks like, I will have to make form block myself.

Comment: If you're using Entity Reference (instead of Node Reference) you should use, entity reference prepopulate, https://drupal.org/project/entityreference_prepopulate

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this question already on [another question.](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44810/prepopulate-entity-reference-field-from-url-in-node-create-form-block/163782#163782) Here is the full answer i provided there:

For the benefit of those who encounter this same problem without a solution, this module: [Entity Reference Prepopulate Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_prepopulate_token) will provide a perfect solution. Please make sure you are using the latest dev version of [Entity Reference Prepopulate](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_prepopulate) module (as at 2015-Jun-10 or higher).

After enabling the module, go to the content type edit page and scroll down to where you have "Provider" and enter the following comma separated values in the text box provided under "Tokens and panel pane context":

> %node:nid, [current-page:url:unaliased:args:value:1]

Just enter the above values in the box and **select the optional checkbox for this provider option to activate it**, hide the field from the user also if desired, to avoid editing. I've tested it, It works!

According to the module page:

> This module supplements Entityreference prepopulate module (dev
>   version is required) by adding prepopulate provider which sets default
>   field values using tokens and replacement patterns of panel pane
>   contexts.
>
> Two kind of patterns can be used for prepopulating entity reference
>   fields:
>
> Tokens, e.g [current-page:url:unaliased:args:value:1] (it returns
>   value "100" for address "node/100", Token module is required).
>   Replacement patterns of panel pane contexts, e.g. %node:nid (it
>   returns node identifier if the form containing entity reference field
>   is placed on node view page created by Page manager). Panels module is
>   required for using these patterns.